# openshift : need to edit httpd.conf to enable or add directive according to my needs but it's not work

Tags: openshift

i've build my application on localhost and running it without any error. i choose openshift to host my application code but i have a problem to make it works perfectly like on my localhost.

i want to add directive of AllowEncodedSlashes and set it to On in my apache2 configuration file, i have tried to edit the file from ~/php/configuration/etc/conf/httpd.conf and then restart the server using ctl_all restart. but the result are http error code 400 (Bad Request). before i add this directive into httpd.conf the result are http error code 404, i am just not sure if the changes are in effect or not. or apache is bugging?

is there anyone knows howto make this work for me?

Comment: I have a similar problem - I want to be able to edit httpd.conf or openshift.conf. I've posted another question similar about [editing apache configuration files on openshift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391720/editing-httpd-conf-openshift-conf-to-create-an-apache-alias) to this one here with details. Sometimes adding configurations to .htaccess just isn't possible (Alias directives are an example.)

Answer (score 1):

See if you can add it into .htaccess file instead of httpd.conf file. Also the best way to troubleshoot these problems would be by reviewing your application logs for errors. All you have to do is run "rhc tail {appName}" from your client machine (where the rhc client tools are installed). That gives you the current log entries.

To get to the entire log, you'll want to ssh onto the gear(s) on which the language framework/cartridge is installed using this FAQ and run: more ~/{cartridgeID}/logs/*.log
where {cartridgeID} is your framework cartridge like nodejs-0.6, or your embedded cartridge logs like mysql-5.1.

Comment: AllowEncodedSlashes context can be set only from server config, virtual host, references from [apache docs] (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes). i'm trying to find the vhost setting on the cloud server but i could'nt find it where the place. or it just how openshift system workflow operated. one apache thread per one application gear. cause i found phpmyadmin gear configuration is different than my core application gear.

Comment: it means each gear per one apache thread. so it can be means by no vhost configuration on each gear. i could be wrong cause i'm not an expert, just my logic think of that. :D anyway, thanks for your time to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

I created a feature request for this. See [this Trello card](https://trello.com/c/yexysd4x) and feel free to vote it up.