# Editing httpd.conf (openshift.conf) to create an apache Alias

Tags: openshift

## Is there a way to make a simple edit to (httpd.conf) with OpenShift and have it persist across restarts?

```
`${HOME}php/configuration/etc/conf.d/openshift.conf`
```

### Here is what I would like to do:

I just need to make an apache directory alias (NOT a DNS alias) and define a directory with some permissions.

### Here is what I've tried:

1. I manually edited the file on rhc and restarted the app from my local command prompt. This overwrote my edited file with the default cartridge file when the restart was complete.

   `$ rhc app restart`
2. Added some herdoc statements to my deploy script, commited the change, and pushed to rhc (I didn't think this would work but tried it just in case.)

   `#.openshift/action_hooks/deploy
   cat << EOF >> ${HOME}php/configuration/etc/conf.d/openshift.conf 
       all of my edits ...
   EOF`

Is there a smarter way to do this or must I build my own cartridge to make a simple edit to httpd.conf?

Thanks for your help is much appreciated!

Jay

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer to my own question:

After looking through the documentation for creating a cartridge the answer was staring me in the face (section under first steps talks about creating a symlink to the modules directory.)

What I really wanted to do with the alias was to point to files outside of the ApacheDocument root. FollowSymLinks is enabled in the cartridge, so all I had to do was create a symlink and it did exactly what I was trying to accomplish with the Alias (not sure why I didn't see that sooner).

So instead of this in the apache conf file...

`Alias /publicly-visible-alias "/some/path/outside/of/document/root" 
<Directory "/some/path/outside/of/document/root">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>`

I used this in the .openshift/action_hooks/deploy

`ln -s /some/path/outside/of/document/root ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/sub-directory/publicly-visible-alias`

The .htaccess file inside of /publicly-visible-alias directory took care of all the other details (mod_rewrites, document index, etc... etc...)

Hope this helps someone else.

Jay

Comment: I don't get it, so you put the 'Alias /publicly... </Directory>' in .htaccess inside your repo and edit the action_hooks instead?